# UDP server using self-signed SSL certificates

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I need to write a UDP server which uses self-signed SSL certificates, and the client to connect with this server as well. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

It's called [Datagram Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security), DTLS; TLS modified for datagram protocols.  The Wikipedia article includes links for libraries and sample implementations.

Answer (score 1):

At wolfSSL we recently created an open source JNI wrapper around the lightweight SSL/TLS library, CyaSSL.  It supports both DTLS 1.0 and DTLS 1.2, in addition to the normal SSL standards up to TLS 1.2.

If you're interested, you can learn more and download the GPLv2-licensed version here: http://yassl.com/yaSSL/Products-wolfssljni.html.

Answer (score 0):

Further to @Steve-o's answer, there doesn't appear to be an implementation of DTLS for Java.  I found:

- An SO question about DTLS on Android/Java, which someone answered saying they ended up using JNI to call a native library implementation.
- A thread on the "security-dev" mailing list in which a Sun guy said they had no resources to implement DTLS.